# Elements change after logging into account in Selenium

Tags: java, html, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I am facing difficulty finding elements using Xpath in selenium. I have a payment page and a field to enter the credit card number. When I simply write a script to enter the credit card number using id it is working. The problem comes when I log into a wallet before entering my CC details. After logging into the wallet, there are two id's by the same name. The script works when I use absolute xpath but that changes when I give the script to someone else.

Html before before into wallet

```
<form autocomplete="off" name="creditcard-form" method="post" action="submitTransaction?MID=oIVSOk48659529909784&ORDER_ID=PARCEL675442&route=" id="card" class="cc-form validated">
        <input type="hidden" name="txnMode" value="CC" />
        <input type="hidden" name="txn_Mode" value="CC" />
        <input type="hidden" name="channelId" value="WEB" />
        <input type="hidden" name="AUTH_MODE" value="3D" />
        <input type="hidden" name="CARD_TYPE" id="cardType" value="" />
        <input type="hidden" name="walletAmount" id="walletAmountCC" value="0" />
        <ul class="grid">
            <li class="mb20 card-wrapper">
                <label class="mb10" for="cardNumber">ENTER CREDIT CARD NUMBER</label>
                <p class="cd">

                    <input autocomplete="off" type="text" name="" class="ccCardNumber  text-input large-input c cardInput type-tel" id="cn" size="16" maxlength="19" style="width: 278px" data-type="cc" value="">
                    <input type="hidden" name="cardNumber" value="" class="required">
                </p>
```

After logging into Wallet:

```
<input type="hidden" name="txnMode" value="CC" />
        <input type="hidden" name="txn_Mode" value="CC" />
        <input type="hidden" name="channelId" value="WEB" />
        <input type="hidden" name="AUTH_MODE" value="3D" />
        <input type="hidden" name="CARD_TYPE" id="cardType" value="" />
        <input type="hidden" name="walletAmount" id="walletAmountCC" value="0" />
        <input type="hidden" name="addMoney" value="1" />
        <ul class="grid">
            <li class="mb20 card-wrapper">
                <label class="mb10" for="cardNumber">ENTER CREDIT CARD NUMBER</label>
                <p class="cd">

                    <input autocomplete="off" type="text" name="" class="ccCardNumber  text-input large-input c cardInput type-tel" id="cn" size="16" maxlength="19" style="width: 278px" data-type="cc" value="">
                    <input type="hidden" name="cardNumber" value="" class="required">
                </p>
```

Please help as I am new to programming and can't figure out how to handle this

Comment: Please add your code and tell us what is the element you are trying to get. I don't see any difference between to html blocks.

Comment: Two element in a DOM should not have same ID. We can see only one id with value 'cn'. Are you talking about the element having id='cn' ?

Comment: Hi, Yes the id='cn'. Both the piece of code is actually before and after logging into wallet account. The id remains the same. The script is able to find the element before I log into the element (before Logging there is just one id=cn) however after logging there are two id's with the name of cn

Comment: Two elements with same id in a DOM is not good.  Try some other type of locator or relative xpath. Or check, your DOM might have some iframe too. If you have iframe in DOM, then switch to it first to have access to the elements in iframe.

Comment: It is worth saying that xpath is particularly slow (especially in IE), I would typically use css selectors before I use XPath. There are certain instances when xpath is your only option though.

Comment: Which one are the two elements having id `cn`

Comment: Could you share other element as well which have same id attribute value as `cn`??? And let us know is both element with same id value present in the same form??

Comment: Try once using `cssSelector` as `driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("form#card input.ccCardNumber#cn"));` and let me know